# PL/SQL VARCHAR2 Max Length

Tags: oracle11g

I can't seem to use a VARCHAR2 of more than 4000 chars in 11G, but I see that I should be able to get to 32776.

```
PROCEDURE prcName
         (piCoSite              IN CHAR
         ,piRaciId              IN NUMBER
         ,piDept                IN VARCHAR2
         ,poRecordset          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 

  locSql1     VARCHAR2(32000 CHAR);

BEGIN


  locSql1 :=
  'SELECT' ||
     '  H.TABLE_HEAD_ID ' ||
     ' ,H.TABLE_HEAD_DEPT ' ||
     ' ,H.TABLE_HEAD_DESCRIPTION ' ||
     ' ,H.TABLE_HEAD_STATUS ' ||
     ' ,H.TABLE_HEAD_SCOPE ' ||
     ' ,H.TABLE_HEAD_ORIGINATOR ' ||
     ' ,H.TABLE_HEAD_SUB_CATEGORY ' ||
     ' ,H.TABLE_HEAD_HIGH_RISK ' ||
     ' ,TRIM(C0.CNTCT_FIRSTNAME) || '' '' || TRIM(C0.CNTCT_SURNAME) wsRaisedBy ' ||
     ' ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_EMPLOYEES E WHERE E.TABLE_EMPS_CO_SITE = H.TABLE_HEAD_CO_SITE AND E.TABLE_EMPS_ID = H.TABLE_HEAD_ID) wsNoEmployees ' ||
     ' ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_TASKS     T WHERE T.TABLE_TASK_CO_SITE = H.TABLE_HEAD_CO_SITE AND T.TABLE_TASK_ID = H.TABLE_HEAD_ID) wsNoActions ' ||
  ' FROM TABLE_HEADER H ' ||
  ' LEFT  JOIN CONTACTS C0 ' ||
  '         ON C0.CNTCT_CO_SITE    = H.TABLE_HEAD_CO_SITE ' ||
  '        AND C0.CNTCT_CODE       = H.TABLE_HEAD_ORIGINATOR  ' ||
  ' WHERE  H.TABLE_HEAD_CO_SITE      =  ''' || piCoSite  || '''' ||
  '   AND (H.TABLE_HEAD_ID           =  ''' || piRaciId  || '''' || ' OR ''' || piRaciId || ''' = 0)      ' ||
  '   AND (H.TABLE_HEAD_DEPT        IN (''' || piDept    || ''' )     OR ''' || piDept   || ''' IS NULL ) ' ||
  '   AND (H.TABLE_HEAD_ORIGINATOR  IN ('   || piUser    ||   ' )     OR ''' || piUser   || ''' IS NULL ) ' ||
  '   AND (H.TABLE_HEAD_STATUS      IN ('   || piStatus  ||   ' )     OR ''' || piStatus || ''' IS NULL ) ' ||
  ' ORDER BY TABLE_HEAD_ID ';

  dbms_output.put_line(locSql1);

  OPEN poRecordset FOR locSql1;
```

When I copy/paste the locSql1 variable it's nowhere near 32000 chars, but it's getting truncated.

Is there something within the Database to change or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: In **SQL** a varchar can not be longer then 4000 bytes. In **PL/SQL** (e.g. in a variable) a VARCHAR can be up to 32k

Comment: I know.  It's not in SQL it's in PL/SQL.  The variable is locSql1, yet when I build up the SQL, it gets truncated.

Comment: Maybe `dbms_output.put_line()` truncates the value

Comment: When you say "it truncates the value" where are you seeing the truncation? In the dbms_output? Because your code (without opening the cursor) works ok for me; I get the full output returned. Perhaps if you appended `chr(10)||` to the ends of all your lines when setting `locSql1` you might see the full thing? - i.e. you might be seeing a truncated result because the line is simply too long to display in your particular GUI/CLI?

Comment: I've changed to output with the CHR(10) and it looks like it may be the IDE (PL/SQL Developer) truncating the DBMS_OUTPUT.  The code now works so maybe there was a bug before in the whole SQL statement, which I couldn't see as the IDE was truncating it. Thanks for your help.